How to update json with variable array using bash script
I have a json file test.json with below format:
{  
   "environments": 
            {
                "egress": [
                   
                ]
            }
}

I want to add objects under egress field with multiple variable values. I have written a bash script test.sh with below code snippet:
egress_port='[80,443]'
egress_value='[test,test1]'
egress_protocol='[http,https]'
# IFS=','

echo $egress_port
echo $egress_value
echo $egress_protocol

cat test.json |
jq  --argjson port "$egress_port" \
   --argjson value "$egress_value" \
   --argjson protocol "$egress_protocol" \
   '.environments.egress = ([$port, $value, $protocol] | transpose |
   map ({port: .[0], type: "external", value: .[1], protocol: .[2]}))'

I want json to be updated in below format:
{  
   "environments": 
            {
                "egress": [
                   {
                    "port": "80", 
                    "type": "external", 
                    "value": "test", 
                    "protocol": "http"
                   },
                   {
                    "port": "443", 
                    "type": "external", 
                    "value": "test1", 
                    "protocol": "https"
                   }
                ]
            }
}

When i run it, it throws an error:
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson

Can someone help me here?

Don't build the jq script using variable expansion. If $value_array contains ", the script generated this way is not syntactically valid and jq cannot run it. Pass the value(s) to the script as argument(s) using --arg or --argjson. See the jq documentation for details: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq

The line read -a port_array <<< "$egress_port" does not make any sense, if the values are already stored in an array. What is your exact use case? Are the ports and protocols known by your script or they are read from outside?

Start with JSON arrays, not bash arrays, for your input data.
egress_ports='[80, 44]'
egress_values='["test", "test1"]'
egress_protocols='["http", "https"]'

These will be passed as arguments to the jq filter directly, from which you will

Create a nested array [[80, 443], ["test", "test1"], ["http", "https"]]
Transpose this to [[80, "test", "http"], [443, "test1", "https"]]
Build an array of objects using each subarray as a separate object
Assign (or merge, with |=) this final array directly to .environments.egress.


jq  --argjson ports "$egress_ports" \
   --argjson values "$egress_values" \
   --argjson protocols "$egress_protocols" \
   '.environments.egress = ([$ports, $values, $protocols] | transpose |
   map ({port: .[0], type: "external", value: .[1], protocol: .[2]}))' test.json


If you do want to use actual bash arrays, you'll need to loop:
ports=(80 443)
values=(test test1)
protocols=(http https)
json=$(< test.json)

for i in "${!ports[@]}"; do
    json=$(
        echo "$json" \
        | jq --arg port "${ports[i]}" \
             --arg value "${values[i]}" \
             --arg protocol "${protocols[i]}" \
          '.environments.egress += [
            {$port, $value, $protocol, type: "external"}
          ]'
    )
done

After this, the json variable contains
{
  "environments": {
    "egress": [
      {
        "port": "80",
        "value": "test",
        "protocol": "http",
        "type": "external"
      },
      {
        "port": "443",
        "value": "test1",
        "protocol": "https",
        "type": "external"
      }
    ]
  }
}


Thank you @glenn for your response. I have tried this as well. But it returns blank when i echo $json.
`
ports=(80 443)
values=(test test1)
protocols=(http https)
json=$(< test.json)
for i in "${!ports[@]}"; do
json=$(
echo "$json" 
| jq --arg port "${ports[i]}" 
--arg value "${values[i]}" 
--arg protocol "${protocols[i]}" 
'.environments.egress += [
{$port, $value, $protocol, type: "external"}
]'
)
done
echo $json
`
** sh test.sh returns blank line. **

sh does not implement arrays. bash does (as well as zsh and ksh)

Its still not returning any value in $json variable. In my previous comment it was reading existing values from test.json file.
#!/bin/bash
ports=(80,443)
values=(test,test1)
protocols=(http,https)
for i in "${!ports[@]}"; do
json=$(
echo "$json" 
| jq --arg port "${ports[i]}" 
--arg value "${values[i]}" 
--arg protocol "${protocols[i]}" 
'.environments.egress += [
{$port, $value, $protocol, type: "external"}
]'
)
done
i run bash test.sh, $json returns empty value.

bash array elements are separated by whitespace, not commas

You're forgetting to initialize the json variable to the initial contents of the test.json file
